# ASP/C# regex for youtube video

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems adjusting my Regex originally used with Javascript to use with ASP.NET Regular Expression Validator Control.

I'm currently using:

```
(?:https?://)?(?:www\\.)?(?:youtu\\.be/|youtube\\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|.*v=))([\\w-]{10,12})($|&).*
```

but it doesn't work. (Always returns validation error)

I also wanted to know if I can use regex to extract youtube ID from the video URL, and how?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please update your title with your specific problem. Your question isn't clear at all. You should read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RegEx for validating a youtube URL and extracting the Video_ID:

```
^(?:https?\:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v\=))([\w-]{10,12})(?:$|\&|\?\#).*
```

Escaped RegEx:

```
^(?:https?\\:\\/\\/)?(?:www\\.)?(?:youtu\\.be\\/|youtube\\.com\\/(?:embed\\/|v\\/|watch\\?v\\=))([\\w-]{10,12})(?:$|\\&|\\?\\#).*
```

Test here: http://fiddle.re/w1nn6

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Altrough it works on every normal YT link, it also matches something like this:
cat://////dog.youtube.com/pony?cow=Vb1pdvvoVoQ

Comment: wow, that was funny :) I just repaired your initial regex first. Updated now with some more validation

Comment: An end quote is helpful if you're fishing it out of html text (more than a url): (?:$|\\&|\\?\\#) => (?:$|\&|\?\#|"")

Comment: @Parmenides thanks, for those needing it your comment is useful. But the answer in the original format will last longer if unbounded at the end :)