# How to extract and validate the id from a youtube video link?

Tags: regex, youtube

I found this RegEx for extracting youtube ID's:

```
#^http(?:s?)://(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?(?:.*?&(?:amp;)?)?v=|\.be/)([\w‌​\-]+)(?:&(?:amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?#i
```

Now I'm trying to modify the RegEx to extract the youtube id for a youtube URL in this format:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESUYMoJVpYo&feature=share&a=rRL4kwOAewcP9KzId6Ks4A

How do I make sure I get the Id extracted from all possible url formats...

Comment: To make people want to answer you should rewrite you question. Describe what you trying to achieve, what did you try and what doesn't work. In current question view it's hard to understand all these. Better do all it after some googling. Also, as you see, not all people here are friendly and some downvode or want close your question without explain the reason. Ignore them and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice hope it's more clear what I want now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP/C# regex for youtube video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313354/asp-c-regex-for-youtube-video)

Answer (score 1):

URLs aren't normally parsed by regular expression. If you want to modify them in any way, then you probably shouldn't use them.

URLs use what's called a [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to pass parameters to a page. The beginning of the query string is marked by a question mark and followed by an ampersand delimited list of name/value pairs.

For example, using your own url: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESUYMoJVpYo&feature=share&a=rRL4kwOAewcP9KzId6Ks4A

```
Page request: www.youtube.com/watch
Whole query string: ?v=ESUYMoJVpYo&feature=share&a=rRL4kwOAewcP9KzId6Ks4A
Name/Value pairs:
  v       -> ESUYMoJVpYo
  feature -> share
  a       -> rRL4kwOAewcP9KzId6Ks4A
```

If you want to parse/modify the URL, do so by breaking down the query string. That'll be much more reliable than trying to write a RegEx for it.

Comment: @eundd That sounds like a different question than what you posted.

Comment: This does not answer the question and your assertion is wrong *'URLs aren't normally parsed by regular expression'* even if it's good advice.

Comment: I assumed it was just a token parser.